# Audio Stream stops playing after removing headphones

Tags: ios, media-player, audio-streaming

I am using the Media Player Framework to play an audio stream from the web.

Everything works just fine except the fact that when I plug headphones in the jack of the device and then remove it - the audio stops playing?!

Do you know of this phenomena and do you know if one can do something about it?

Thanks for any kind of hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is a feature built into the os.  Doesnt the music player also do this?